# What's wrong with this array search function?

Tags: php, arrays

I have written the following function to search an multi-dimensional array by key, but if I call the function with key `uri`, it appends arrays having key `0` to the found array. What's wrong?

```
function search_arr($array, $key, &$found) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $each) {
        if ($k == $key) {
            // output of "print $k = $key" is "0 = uri"
            $found[] = $each;
        }   
        if (is_array($each)) {
            search_arr($each, $key, $found);
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [===](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to force a value *and* type match. You get zeros because comparing 0 and "uri" is `true` - think of them as both evaluating to 0. For complete details of how PHP handles these 'loose' comparisons, see this [section of the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose).

Comment: Why uri is equal to zero? I thaught 0 is equal to null strings

Comment: @Nima Zero is equal to `false`. `null` is equal to `null` or empty string.

Comment: Ok, but why 'uri' is equal to false?